# Invoke a method using a string from Console.Readline

Tags: c#, string, class, methods

I have source code that does nothing.

```
if (tok[1] == "?")
{
    Type _t = typeof(Help);
    Help _h = new Help();
    MethodInfo[] _m = _t.GetMethods();
    foreach (MethodInfo m in _m)
    {
        if (m.Name.CompareTo(tok[0]) == 0)
        {
            m.Invoke(_h, null);
        }
    }
}
```

It's supposed to invoke a static method from a different class to the if statement, when the user types, say, command ? into the console. The tokenizer works, the method is public, and this is the code I'm using.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: have you tried stepping through the code? where does it not do what you expect?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the static methods you will have to add a BindingFlagsEnum.

```
MethodInfo[] _m = _t.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static|BindingFlags.Public );
```

Comment: You might want to throw in a check that (m.GetParameters().Length == 0) before you call.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GetMethod` instead:

```
typeof(Help).GetMethod(tok[0]).Invoke(null,null);
```

Since the method is `**static**`, you need to pass `null` in first parameter.

Comment: If you do it like this check for nullness on the return of GetMethod(tok[0]).

Comment: Still does nothing. How can I find out what the problem is when it throws no exceptions, errors or anything? I'm using c# express 2010.

Comment: Post the declarations from your help class.